# Setting Axis Label offset in core plot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, bar-chart

After setting the bar offset , the axis labels are not displaying at the center of the bar and getting misplaced. Can any one help me with this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `barOffset` moves the centers of the bars away from the bar locations provided by the datasource. If the axis labels are at the bar locations, they won't line up with the bars.

Possible solutions:

1. Set the `barOffset` to zero (0).
2. Change the axis labeling policy to place the labels under the bars. This will also move any tick marks on the axis unless you make custom labels.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the answer.I was just thinking for making custom labels but i think with custom labels also i wont be getting ticks at the center of the bars as i need to draw bar for specific value and that is not giving perfect result.

Comment: We need more information about what you're trying to do. Why do you need to use the bar offset? Do you have more than one bar plot?

Comment: First of all thanks again for you quick reply. Let me give you some brief about it. We're using  core plot to display group chart in our cocoa application. Because of that we need to take two & sometime three bar in one graph. In that case, we're giving second bar offset as the width of first bar So, title is not displaying with centre align to both bar. It would be great if you can provide some solution for label to centre align both bar. ( without taking custom label )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With two bars, give one a negative offset and the other an equal positive offset. With three, give one a negative offset, the middle one a zero offset, and the other a positive offset.